# Use of case in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column which will have multiple values - cash, cheque,dd,pdc and on the basis of that I have to show value in other columns like if the column is having value cash then cash column value  will be 'YES' and other cheque, dd columns will be 'NO' and if column value  is cash, cheque then cash column and cheque column will be 'Yes' and dd column will be 'No' and so on. Is it possible that this can be done with the use of case in select statement. Please guide.

Comment: Post your table schema and existing query.

Comment: It's not best-practice to have columns that contain text to represent boolean values like "YES" and "NO" - why do you want this instead of using `NUMBER(1,0)`?

Comment: @Dai: Well, Tom Kyte suggested 'Y' and 'N'. This is the bad thing about the lack of booleans in Oracle, one must make the rules for the database and all developers must know these rules. Moreover you need a check constraint on every "boolean" column. Too bad it has taken Oracle so long to consider the idea of introducing a BOOLEAN data type. It seems, though, that there are working on it. The request finally got registered as Enh 28146286 (see https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2633)...

Comment: ... Maybe some topics take so long with Oracle, because there are so very few people participating and voting in Oracle Database ideas (https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/database-ideas).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The problem with `'Y'`/`'N'` is that it's not a culture-invariant solution. In Germany they use `'J'`/`'N'`, for example - which is why `NUMBER(1,0)` should be preferred, imo.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. assuming that your table name is payment_table and the column in question is called mode_of_payment:

```
SELECT mode_of_payment, 
CASE
    WHEN mode_of_payment = 'cash' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
END AS is_cash
FROM
payment_table
```

Comment: That's not working this I have already tried... The result is coming no.. If payment mode column is having CASH, CHEQUE then cash and cheque column will be Yes and DD column is no and if payment mode is having single value then that particular columns gets Yes and rest with No

Comment: @Jaspreet Singh: Ah, the value cannot only be `'CASH`'  or `'CHEQUE'`, but also `'CASH, CHEQUE' `. Then you are suffereing from a poor data model. Instead of trying to solve this with a query, fix your data model. Have a row for each payment method; don't concatenate them in one string.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner... That's correct this is because of the poor data model that was given to me...however, if I would like ,we can't correct the data, how it will be possible with the query. Please guide because I need to set different columns on the basis of the data...

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  And this would not be possible to write n number of case statements

Comment: You can use `CASE WHEN mode_of_payment LIKE '%CASH%' THEN 'YES'`... but it's poor design as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

- `case .. when` statement
- `decode`

--

```
Case when upper(col) = 'CASH' then
     'YES' else 'NO' end as is_cash
-- or
Decode(upper(col), 'CASH', 'YES','NO') as is_cash
```

Do it for other columns yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might help

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Col = 'Cheque'
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END AS Cheque
    , CASE 
        WHEN Col = 'Cash'
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END AS Cash
    , CASE 
        WHEN Col = 'dd'
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END AS dd
    , CASE 
        WHEN Col = 'pdc '
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END AS pdc
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use it for optimal soltion:

```
select mode_payment,
(case when mode_payment = 'CASH' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) cash,
(case when mode_payment = 'RTGS' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) RTGS,
(case when mode_payment = 'CHEQUE' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) CHEQUE,
(case when mode_payment = 'NEFT' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) NEFT,
(case when mode_payment = 'DD' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) DD
from tablename
```